# Jquery Selecting Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Sorry I'm new to this. I have a problem with selecting an element inside my nav list

```
<ul class="subnav">
<li><a href="#">Link 1</a><span class="sub">Description 1</span></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 2</a><span class="sub">Description 2</span></li>
<li><a href="#">Link 3</a><span class="sub">Description 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

I'm looking to create a function that when a user hovers on Link 1, only Description 1 text should appear.

Below is my JQUERY

```
$('ul.subnav li a').hover(function() {

    $('.sub').animate({opacity: "show", top: "5"}, "slow");
}, function() {
    $('.sub').animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-5"}, "slow");
});
```

The problem I am having is when a user hover on any link, all of the description text will appear. How can I tell JQUERY to show only the Description on where the mouse is hovered?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$(this)` to get a reference to only the anchor which is currently hovered along with `.next()` to animate only `span` element which is the next immediate sibling of your hovered anchor:

```
$('ul.subnav li a').hover(function() {
    $(this).next().animate({opacity: "show", top: "5"}, "slow");
}, function() {
   $(this).next().animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-5"}, "slow");
});
```

Comment: or `$(this).closest('li').find('.sub')`

Comment: @MarianTheisen Yes, it's an alternative but `.next()` will be faster in this case.

Comment: i agree, but this will couple it strongly to the sequence of the tags. if somebody adds sth. between `a` and `span`, it'll break

Comment: This turned out to be a simple solution for my very difficult problem thanks Felix for your input it works!

Answer (score 0):

@Felix has a great answer, but you can also use `.siblings()` with your markup.

```
$('ul.subnav li a').hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings().animate({opacity: "show", top: "5"}, "slow");
}, function() {
    $(this).siblings().animate({opacity: "hide", top: "-5"}, "slow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bUZ8j/